# Disabling App Nap in Mavericks

Tags: macos

I want to disable App Nap ***globally*** on a late 2009 iMac desktop running Mavericks, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can by setting NSAppSleepDisabled globally:

```
defaults write -g NSAppSleepDisabled -bool true
```